# Какой правильный формат запроса к БД для работы с полем даты

Tags: php, mysql, дата

У меня такая ситуация. Есть бд где есть поле date_add. Оно указывается в формате DateTime. (2017-12-11 16:43:32)

На сайте есть поле, где пользователь вводит дату, но в формат ввода вот такой: дд.мм.гг. Его менять нельзя.

Как мне получить из бд все записи где date_add >= "16.12.17"

Получается мне как то надо переформатировать значение поля ввода "16.12.17" в корректную дату.

Скрин из БД
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Comment: либо на клиенте (в php) переверните задом наперед и припишите 20 к году, что бы вышло в формате YYYY-MM-DD, он по дефолту в MySQL

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cp_news WHERE 1 AND date_add >= STR_TO_DATE ('16.12.17', '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') ORDER BY date_add DESC

Вот такой запрос. Почему то не отрабатывается корректно

Comment: На верное потому, что вы задали маску год-месяц-день, а дата, как вы сказали выше, у вас день-месяц-год. т.е. маска `%d-%m-%y` (кстати, `y` маленький, у вас же 2 цифры только). И нули в маске не нужны

Comment: В базе данных поле date_add у меня имеет формат 2017-12-11 16:34:32, а пользователь вводит в формате 16.12.17 То что мне сделать что бы верный был запрос?

Comment: В базе данных, вы сказали, у вас поле _типа DateTime_ . У типа DateTime нет формата, оно хранится в двоичном виде. некий формат применяется только при выводе. функция str_to_date преобразует строку в указанном формате во внутреннее представление БД. поэтому в функции задается тот формат в котором ваша  строка, а не в котором вы видите на экране поле из БД. так что, как я и сказал выше `STR_TO_DATE ('16.12.17', '%d-%m-%y')`. Вот если у вас в БД у почему то не datetime, а _строка_, тогда очевидно у нас проблема ...

Comment: SELECT * FROM `cp_news` WHERE 1 AND date_add >= STR_TO_DATE ('16.11.17', '%d-%m-%y') 

Вот этот запрос у меня возвращает 0, но на самом деле записи есть, я к вопросу прикрепил скрин из БД

В бд формат четко указан - datetime

Comment: @WhoIsDT вот в `STR_TO_DATE` надо немного поправить: `SELECT * FROM cp_news WHERE 1 AND date_add >= STR_TO_DATE ('16.11.17', '%d.%m.%y')`

Comment: Дал `select STR_TO_DATE ('16.11.17', '%d-%m-%y')`, он возвращает NULL. у вас в дате точки, а в маске тире. `STR_TO_DATE ('16.11.17', '%d.%m.%y')`

Comment: Ой какой кошмар, точно) блин я вообще туплю, извините. Ваш вариант рабочий, спасибо!